# How to ulpload multiple images in one time using php form?

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

Here, my php script for upload image in server. i want user can upload multiple images on one records. right now, in this code at time only one image can post, user's requirement is they can post multiple images at time. I don't idea how can I possible using arrays. please help. Thanks in advance :)

```
<?php
  include ("connect.php");
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$event = $_POST['evnt_name'];
$image_name = $_FILES['evnt_img']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['evnt_img']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['evnt_img']['size'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['evnt_img']['tmp_name'];

if($event=='' && $image_name==''){

    echo "<script>alert('Any field is empty')</script>";
    exit();
}
if($image_type=="image/jpeg" OR $image_type=="image/png" OR     $image_type=="image/gif")
{
    if($image_size<=50000)
    {
      move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"imagess/$image_name");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('image is large, only 50kb size allowed')</script>";
        exit();
    }

}
else{
    echo "<script>alert('image type is invalid')</script>";
    exit();
}

$query = "insert into event_update (evnt_text,evnt_img) values  ('$event','$image_name')";

   if(mysqli_query($conn,$query))
   {
    echo "<script>alert('Post has been published')</script>";
    exit();
   }
 }
?>
```

And below my simple bootstrap HTML code for form

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form method="POST" action="evntform.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Events Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="evnt_name" placeholder="Write Events Name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>File input</label>
            <input type="file" name="evnt_img[]">
        </div>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<form method="POST" action="evntform.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Events Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="evnt_name" placeholder="Write Events Name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>File input</label>
        <input type="file" name="evnt_img[]" multiple>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
</form>
```

PHP code to select the first image uploaded:

```
  <?php
  include ("connect.php");
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$event = $_POST['evnt_name'];
$image_name = $_FILES['evnt_img'][0]['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['evnt_img'][0]['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['evnt_img'][0]['size'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['evnt_img'][0]['tmp_name'];
....
```

You can use a for loop for every image:

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['evnt_img']);$i++){

$image_name = $_FILES['evnt_img'][$i]['name'];

}
```

J

Comment: well, good.. i newbie tell me how can i use 'Loop' in above code.. plz

Comment: the for loop above counts from 0 to the number of files that is in your array: please see this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp 
Learn whilst you program!

Comment: well, But now problem is front side.. in form user how can select multiple image.. there is just one image selectable.